# NSMutableArray add data to NSTableView creating an empty row?

Tags: objective-c, macos, data-binding, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I've create a function below which will call when a button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)setData:(id)sender{
    
    [_myArrayController addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"James", @"Name",
                            @"Smith",@"Surname", nil]];

}
```

On My `NSTableView` I have two columns both `NSTableViewColumn`s have been binded to the keys above `Name` for the first and `Surname` for the second for the `arrangedObjects` controller key.

When I press the button a new row is created however both column fields are blank rather than saying James Smith.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the table view view based or cell based? What did you bind to what?

Comment: You helped me just by asking a question, it was meant to be cell based but as set as view based - I rebuild the window and all the elements on it so must have forgot to set it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question while i've got your attention, what's the best way to save the NSArrayController data to user defaults?

Comment: It depends on what you want to save. All objects: `_myArrayController.content`, filtered sorted objects: `_myArrayController.arrangedObjects`.